# Safari view controller

Tags: ios, sfsafariviewcontroller

I am new in iOS app development. Currently, I am working on a project which requires the interaction between the app and webpage. I know I can use safari view controller to load a web page within the app, and use done button at the right up corner of the webpage to back to the app. But I want to back to the app by clicking a link in the webpage instead of done button. I could not find any solution for this. Can anyone help? Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 8):

You can do this easily enough with a custom URL scheme.  First add a scheme to your `Info.plist`:

```
<key>CFBundleURLTypes</key>
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>CFBundleURLName</key>
        <string>com.mydomain.MyCallback</string>
        <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
        <array>
            <string>mydomainwebcallback</string>
        </array>
    </dict>
</array>
```

Now, you have a mechanism that will open your app from any URL that is clicked.  In this case, the url would be `mydomainwebcallback://whatever`

Now in your web page loaded in your view controller, add a URL like this:

```
<a href="mydomainwebcallback://whateverinfo">Return to app</a>
```

I am going to simplify here, but you need a reference to your `SFSafariViewController` from your `AppDelegate`.  First in the AppDelegate:

```
import UIKit
import SafariServices

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?
    var safariVC: SFSafariViewController?

    func application(application: UIApplication, handleOpenURL url: NSURL) -> Bool {

        // Here we dismiss the SFSafariViewController
        if let sf = safariVC
        {
            sf.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
        }

        return true
    }
```

As you can see I am keeping the `SFSafariViewController` in the Delegate.  Now in my view controller where I show the VC:

```
import UIKit
import SafariServices

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBAction func showSafariVC(sender: UIButton) {

        if let url = NSURL(string: "https://mywebserver/callback.html")
        {
            let delegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
            delegate.safariVC = SFSafariViewController(URL: url)
            presentViewController(delegate.safariVC!, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
    }
}
```

Now, when you hit the link it will dismiss the `SFSafariViewController`.

Comment: Thank you all. This one gives all the details. It works for me. Thanks.

Comment: @ShalinaHu please accept the answer if it works for you.

Answer (score 0):

this work for me but wkwebview. 
https://github.com/liqichao/wkwebview-test

this example is a sfsafariview but u must use inner with wkwebview
https://github.com/mattneub/Programming-iOS-Book-Examples/blob/master/bk2ch11p552webkit/ch24p825webview/WebViewController.swift